# How to install TensorFlow with Anaconda 3.6.4 in Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I am new to programming with Anaconda and am attempting to install TensorFlow.

Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.|

```
>>> C:> conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.6
```

File "", line 1
    C:> conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.6
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can anyone help explain how to install and activate tensorflow using the Anaconda 3.6.4 prompt?

Comment: do you have `pip3` installed?

Comment: It is generally better to do a little more leg-work on your own before posting here.  If you are reading from a tutorial, you are better served to make sure you've followed the tutorial before posting on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

@dpoak Try this command below, including the link, i think that will help
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

The pip install --upgrade tensorflow/tensorflow-gpu command probably will work for some people but won't work for others, but don't know why